# Как получить внутренность элемента, если я его нашел с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, парсер

Нашел элемент tr кодом

```js
var TRindx=textF.indexOf("<tr height=20 ");
var test=$('tr.td:eq(TRindx)');
```

(не могу сказать что действительно нашел, проверить просто не знаю как)

Как получить его внутренний текст как я получал бы его из кода типа?

```js
var RB=document.getElementById("resultbox").innerHTML
```

```js
Код в main.js
(function(){

$('#progress').hide();
$('#starter').click(parserGo);
var file=$("fileInput").val();
if (typeof file!="undefined"){
 alert(file);
}
var filesExt = ['htm']; // массив расширений
var docx = document.getElementById("fileInput");
 docx.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var parts = $(this).val().split('.'); 
    if(filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) != -1){
        alert('Good!');

  var file = docx.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;

  if (file.type.match(textType)) {
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(e) {
    //console.log(reader.result);
    var textF=reader.result;
    var TRindx=textF.indexOf("<tr height=20 ");
    var $test = $("tr.td:eq(" + TRindx + ")");
    //var test=textF.substr(TRindx+1,341);
    alert(TRindx);
    //document.getElementById("resultbox").innerHTML+= test;
    var $test2=$('tr');
    if($test.length > 0) {
       alert($test.html());
    }
   }
   reader.readAsText(file);
  } else {
   //fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
   alert("File not supported!");
  }
    } else {
        alert('WTF?!');
    }
 });
});
```

```html
код в htm файле

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 14">
<link id=Main-File rel=Main-File href="../&#1053;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1076;&#1086;&#1082;&#1091;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;.xls">
<link rel=File-List href=filelist.xml>
<link rel=Stylesheet href=stylesheet.css>
<style>
<!--table
 {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\,";
 mso-displayed-thousand-separator:" ";}
@page
 {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
 mso-header-margin:.5in;
 mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
-->
</style>
<![if !supportTabStrip]><script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function fnUpdateTabs()
 {
  if (parent.window.g_iIEVer>=4) {
   if (parent.document.readyState=="complete"
    && parent.frames['frTabs'].document.readyState=="complete")
   parent.fnSetActiveSheet(0);
  else
   window.setTimeout("fnUpdateTabs();",150);
 }
}

if (window.name!="frSheet")
 window.location.replace("../&#1053;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1076;&#1086;&#1082;&#1091;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;.xls");
else
 fnUpdateTabs();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]>
</head>

<body link=blue vlink=purple>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=784 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:588pt'>
 <col width=200 span=2 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:7314;
 width:150pt'>
 <col width=40 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1462;width:30pt'>
 <col width=120 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:4388;width:90pt'>
 <col width=40 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1462;width:30pt'>
 <col width=120 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:4388;width:90pt'>
 <col width=64 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr height=21 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl65 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=60 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:45.0pt'>
  <td colspan=6 height=60 class=xl73 width=720 style='border-right:.5pt solid black;
  height:45.0pt;width:540pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl65 width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=21 style='height:15.75pt'>
  <td height=21 class=xl65 width=200 style='height:15.75pt;width:150pt'></td>
  <td class=xl65 width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td colspan=5 style='mso-ignore:colspan'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=80 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:60.0pt'>
  <td height=80 class=xl66 width=200 style='height:60.0pt;width:150pt'>&#1053;&#1072;&#1080;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1086;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;
  &#1086;&#1073;&#1086;&#1088;&#1091;&#1076;&#1086;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1103;</td>
  <td class=xl67 width=200 style='width:150pt'>&#1058;&#1080;&#1087;</td>
  <td class=xl67 width=40 style='width:30pt'>&#1045;&#1076;.
  &#1048;&#1079;&#1084;.</td>
  <td class=xl68>&#1062;&#1077;&#1085;&#1072;</td>
  <td class=xl68>&#1050;-&#1074;&#1086;</td>
  <td class=xl69>&#1057;&#1091;&#1084;&#1084;&#1072;</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl70 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl71 width=200 style='width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl71 width=40 style='width:30pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl70 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl71 width=200 style='width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl71 width=40 style='width:30pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

в htm фале мне надо найти 88 строчку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `.html();` метод:

```js
var $test = $('div');

console.log($test.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>привет!</div>
```

А также:

```
(не могу сказать что действительно нашел, проверить просто не знаю как)
```

Проверяйте длину `jQuery` объекта:

```
var TRindx = textF.indexOf("<tr height=20 ");
var $test = $("tr.td:eq(" + TRindx + ")");

if($test.length > 0) {
   alert($test.html());
}
```

Comment: Странно, нет алерта, значит не нашел он этот элемент. А почему?

Comment: @Михаил скиньте полный код таблицы в свой вопрос, так я не могу сказать.

Comment: Добавил полный код в вопрос.

Comment: Может быть надо так: `$("tr td:eq(" + TRindx + ")");` (убрал точку между `tr` `td`).

Comment: Не работает, может лучше весь текст в одну строку скинуть? и в ней искать? Просто я не знаю как весь текст файла записать в одну строку...